# How to solve multiple unwanted array when output using foreach

Tags: php

When I look at the output of my foreach loop, I get multiple copies of the array itself. The problem is from the output of **exper3.php** below. Here's my code:

file **exper.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Multiple form with output</title></head>
<body>
<form action="exper1.php" method="POST">
    Banyaknya nilai yang anda masukkan 
    <input type="text" name="nilai">
    <input type="submit" name="kirim" value="kirim">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

file **exper1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Multiple form with output</title></head>
<body>
<form action="exper1.php" method="POST">
    Banyaknya nilai yang anda masukkan 
    <input type="text" name="nilai">
    <input type="submit" name="kirim" value="kirim">
</form>
<br>
<form action="exper3.php" method="POST">
<?php 
$nilai = $_POST['nilai'];
    $wtf = $nilai/$nilai;
    $i = $nilai + 1;
    $counter = 1;
do {
        echo "Nilai ke-"; 
        echo $counter;
        echo " : ";
        echo "<input type='text' name='hasil[]'>";
        echo "<br>";
        $counter++;
        $wtf++;
    } while ($wtf<$i);
?>
<input type="submit" name="simpan" value="simpan">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

file **exper3.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Multiple form with output</title></head>
<body>
<form action="exper1.php" method="POST">
    Banyaknya nilai yang anda masukkan 
    <input type="text" name="nilai">
    <input type="submit" name="kirim" value="kirim">
</form>
<br>
<?php
$hasil = $_POST['hasil'];
$i=1;
    foreach ($hasil as $value) {
        echo "Nilai ke ".$i++." adalah ".join('<br>Nilai ke ' .$i++. ' adalah ', $hasil)."<br>";;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**the output**

[Output of file expert.php: First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVzTp.png)

[Output of file exper1.php: Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bTBe.png)

[Output of file exper3.php: Third, the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9IiE.png)

The intended output of **exper3.php** should be like this:

```
Nilai ke 1 adalah 343
Nilai ke 2 adalah 732
Nilai ke 3 adalah 958
```

not like this:

```
Nilai ke 1 adalah 343
Nilai ke 2 adalah 732
Nilai ke 2 adalah 958
Nilai ke 3 adalah 343
Nilai ke 4 adalah 732
Nilai ke 4 adalah 958
Nilai ke 5 adalah 343
Nilai ke 6 adalah 732
Nilai ke 6 adalah 958
```

What is wrong with my code ? Thanks

Comment: Whats the purpose of the `$wtf = $nilai/$nilai;` something divided by itself is always 1

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it's for looping purpose. The inputted value i convert it into 1 and then i insert it into do..while loop. So that, the looping will stop when it reach before the inputted value

Comment: I can see that, what I meant is you could replace it with `1`, because that is what it is almost always equal to.  eg.  `5\5=1`, `23/23=1` but if you do `0/0` Well, I don't think that is `= 1` as it's `b>Warning</b>:  Division by zero`  So effectively you have 1, except if you have 0 in which case you have a warning/error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join and foreach duplicate each other in this case - join already operates on multiple values.

```
foreach ($hasil as $value) {
    echo "Nilai ke ".$i++." adalah ".$value."<br />";
}
```

would give you the result you want

Comment: Thanks! it worked!, Previously i use almost the same code that you gave me. but the output keep asking me about "array to string conversion". Something must be wrong with my previous code.

Comment: Maybe you were accidentally echoing .$hasil instead of .$value - that would give you an array to string conversion warning as well as wrong output

Comment: oh.. ok. i'll remember that. Thanks for your help once again.